# What am I missing? MongoDB keeps giving me the same error no matter what I try

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to insert a document into mongodb under the inspections collection but no matter what I try, I get an error!

The code I am trying:

```
db.inspections.insertOne({
"_id": 20032-2020-ACME,
 certificate_number: 9998888,
 business_name: "ACME Explosives",
 date: newDate("09-05-2022"),
 result: "Business Padlocked",
 sector: "Explosive Retail Dealer-999",
 {
 "address":"number->1721" "street-> Boom Road" "city->BRONX" "zip->10463"}
 }
```

This is the error I keep getting:

```
E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: expected property name, got '{' :
```

I have tried to replace the brackets, tried formatting in a different way, tried using without quotes or switching quotes around but each attempt gives me this same error.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error actually tells you what is wrong.
The item you are trying to insert is not valid json.

Most likely you have forgotten to put a key before the `{` that sits before "address". Also, in that same line you don't have any comma's to seperate the key value pairs.

I believe you will have more success with

```
db.inspections.insertOne({
"_id": "20032-2020-ACME",
 certificate_number: 9998888,
 business_name: "ACME Explosives",
 date: newDate("09-05-2022"),
 result: "Business Padlocked",
 sector: "Explosive Retail Dealer-999",
 address: {
    "number":"1721",
    "street":"Boom Road",
    "city":"BRONX", 
    "zip":"10463"
 }
}
```

The `address:`  part is what it is truely complaining about now. Most likely it would have complained about the lack of comma's after fixing `address:`. Or your use of `->` instead of `:`.

Also, it may also be that keys must be quoted.

EDIT: Also just noticed that your original ID is probably being interpreted as integer minus integer minus string/unknown var. I can't say what the effect might be of that, but I'm gonna assume you want that to be the id, as a string. To do so, I've put quotes around the `20032-2020-ACME`

Comment: Thank you so much! This had me pulling my hair out. I have zero experience with mongo especially when it comes to documents so I am surprised I got this far! Thank you!

Comment: @GuillyStudiesCode Couple more pointers. 1. Mongo itself communicates in bson, basically binary form of json. If you want to validate simple documents. Just dump em in an online validator. 2. The _id field can be autogenerated. You don't have to specify it. Mongo will then automatically create an ObjectID to fill in that field. (Looks like a 16 char hexadecimal string, but is in fact a slightly different type).